# Vue3 Composition API. Object from localStorage always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, local-storage

I'm using Vue3 Composition API. Basically, I'm trying to obtain data from an object stored in localStorage, but I am always receiving that it is undefined, even though it does exist 100%.

The error is: `"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $setup.habits.value is undefined"`

My local storage object: `habits:"[{"habitName":"Dance","completedDates":["2023-12-27","2023-12-26","2023-12-28"]},{"habitName":"Act","completedDates":["2023-12-28"]}]"`

Refer to the habits variable that gets an item from local storage. Here is my component:

````
import { ref, nextTick, watchEffect } from 'vue'
import AddHabit from '../components/EditHabits/AddHabit.vue'


let habits = ref(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('habits')))

let editingHabit = ref()

watchEffect(() => {
    habits.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('habits'))
})

const editHabit = async (habit) => {
    editingHabit.value = habit

    await nextTick()
    const inputField = document.getElementById(habit.habitName)
    inputField.focus()
    inputField.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            const index = habits.value.findIndex(h => h.habitName === habit.habitName) 
            
            habits.value[index].habitName = editingHabit.value.habitName
            localStorage.setItem('habits', JSON.stringify(habits.value))
            
            editingHabit.value = null
            
        }
    })
}


</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <h4>Your Current Habits: </h4>
        <div id="total-habits" v-if="habits.value.length">
            <div class="dropdown" v-for="habit in habits.value" :key="habit.habitName">
                <p id="habitEntry" v-if="editingHabit.value !== habit"> {{ habit.habitName }}</p>
                <input :id="habit.habitName" v-else v-model.lazy="editingHabit.value.habitName" type="text">                
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <div @click="editHabit(habit)">Edit</div>
                    <div>Pause</div>
                    <div>Delete</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div v-else>No Habits Yet!</div>
        
        
        <h4>Hover on a habit to edit it!</h4>
    </div>
    
    <AddHabit/>
</template>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vue3 in template, for read or modify your variable you need to just call it without `.value` unlike in script section

So `<div v-if="habits.value.length" id="total-habits">` becomes `<div v-if="habits.length" id="total-habits">`.

With just this modification, you should be able to clear your code.
Here's your code, but modified:

```js
<script setup>
import {
  nextTick,
  ref,
  watchEffect
} from 'vue'

const habits = ref([])
const editingHabit = ref({})

watchEffect(() => {
  habits.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('habits'))
})

const editHabit = async (habit) => {
  editingHabit.value = habit

  await nextTick()
  const inputField = document.getElementById(habit.habitName)
  inputField.focus()
  inputField.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      const index = habits.value.findIndex(h => h.habitName === habit.habitName)

      habits.value[index].habitName = editingHabit.value.habitName
      localStorage.setItem('habits', JSON.stringify(habits.value))

      editingHabit.value = null
    }
  })
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h4>Your Current Habits: </h4>
    <div v-if="habits.length" id="total-habits">
      <div v-for="habit in habits" :key="habit.habitName" class="dropdown">
        <p v-if="editingHabit !== habit" id="habitEntry"> {{ habit.habitName }}</p>
        <input v-else :id="habit.habitName" v-model.lazy="editingHabit.habitName" type="text">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <div @click="editHabit(habit)">Edit</div>
          <div>Pause</div>
          <div>Delete</div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div v-else>No Habits Yet!</div>
    <h4>Hover on a habit to edit it!</h4>
  </div>

  <!--  <AddHabit/>-->
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

For more information: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html